# Why is the number of components of Lie group finite?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

The following quote is from *An Introduction to Lie Group and Lie Algebra* by Alexander Kirillov. By "discrete" he means that $|G/G^0|$ is finite. However, according to *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by J. Lee, a topological manifold has countable (not finite in general) components. So, I'd like to know what condition makes lie group to have a finite components.

[image]

Comment: It isn't. ${}{}$

Comment: For example, one wants that a closed subgroup of a Lie group itself, but that is false if we insisted in that the number of components be finite, as the group of integers inside the additive group of real number shows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That solved my question.